# numpy Tries to Allocate More Memory than Available in Windows

Tags: python, c, numpy, memory-management, malloc

When `numpy` is asked to allocate memory for an array, it makes a call to `malloc`. If the call returns a NULL pointer, then `numpy` reports an exception like this:

```
np.random.randn(1000000 * 1000 * 1000)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.28 TiB for an array with shape (1000000000000,) and data type float64
```

I am running Python 3.7.9, 64-bit.

On my Windows 10 machine, I have 32 GB of physical memory and 64 GB of total virtual memory, for a total of 96 GB.

```
systeminfo
Total Physical Memory:     32,716 MB
Available Physical Memory: 16,726 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  65,484 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 46,727 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    18,757 MB
```

Suppose I enter these commands:

```
size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 13
X = np.random.randn(size)
```

That comes to 8 bytes * 13 giga-elements = 104 GB, which is more than the physical memory plus virtual memory on the machine.

`numpy` does not throw an exception and apparently starts allocating memory.

QUESTION: Why does `numpy` not throw an exception and stop? This may actually be a question about `malloc` in C.

AFTERMATH: I watched memory usage reported in Task Manager climb to 99%. About one minute later, the system became unresponsive. I let the test run for 20 more minutes before I rebooted the machine with the Reset button.

Comment: Keep in mind that the ordinary mortals among us, users of Python and numpy, are familiar with memory errors, and can estimate the array sizes, we haven't dug into the `numpy` source code, tracing it all the way down to the `malloc` calls.

Comment: Why C++? NumPy is implemented in C, that's why it uses `malloc`.

Comment: Corrected to C from C++.

Comment: Becauseon modern OSes 'malloc()' actually reserves address space rather than allocate bytes. The memory is claimed when it is written to

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the `numpy` code and verified that it relies on `malloc` to determine whether an array can be allocated. `malloc` is a function in the C standard library. In Windows 10, it is implemented as a wrapper around `HeapAlloc`. See [HeapAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc)

`HeapAlloc` in `kernel32.dll` is forwarded to `RtlAllocateHeap` in `ntdll.dll`.See [Function Forwarding](https://flylib.com/books/en/4.419.1.139/1/) and [RtlAllocateHeap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlallocateheap)

The source code of `ntdll.dll` is not publicly available, and it is unclear how `RtlAllocateHeap` decides whether there is enough memory to allocate.